# Symfony 5 security.interactive_login event not called

Tags: symfony, events, symfony5, symfony-security, symfony-eventdispatcher

I want to use the `security.interactive_login` event to update my User's last login field.

The event is successfully registered:

```
php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher security.interactive_login

Registered Listeners for "security.interactive_login" Event
===========================================================

 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ----------
  Order   Callable                                                                 Priority
 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ----------
  #1      App\EventSubscriber\UserLocaleSubscriber::onSecurityInteractiveLogin()   0
 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ----------
```

But it lands on *Not called listeners* in the Symfony profiler.

This is the event subscriber:

```php
class UserLocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        $user->setLastLoginAt(new DateTime());
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin',
        ];
    }
}
```

And there is my *security.yaml* file:

```yaml
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js|fonts)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: app_login               # where to redirect after logout
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800                # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/(?!login), roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The *LoginAuthenticator* class is Symfony's default generated one.

Why the ***interactive login*** event is not called?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using the new(ish) authentication manager, the `INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` event is replaced with the `LoginSuccessEvent`.

```
# my subscriber
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            //SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin',
            LoginSuccessEvent::class => 'onLoginSuccess'
        ];
    }
    public function onLoginSuccess(LoginSuccessEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $user->setCount($user->getCount() + 1);
        $this->em->flush();
        //dd($user);
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is explicitly documented yet.  Like many upgrade deprecations, the code is very confusing.  I tried to trace through what was happening and quickly got lost (once again) in the Security forest.

Events are talked about [here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-updated-security-system).

I discovered this behavior by creating a fresh 5.1 project, running `make:auth` and adding a listener for both events.  But I forgot to add enable_authenticator_manager: true to the security config.

So the `INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` event was fired.  After enabling the new manager, the `LoginSuccessEvent` was fired.  Notice that the new event has some additional helper methods such as getUser.  Makes the code a tiny bit cleaner.

Off-topic but I would caution against flushing the entity manager inside of a listener.  It can be a bit unpredictable depending on what else is going on.  Might consider just getting the database connection and executing a SQL update.

Comment: Thanks for the notice on the persist here! I didn't know that. Truth is my actual code contains translation logic here, I replaced it with this for the sake of clarity, but it is always good to know :)