# Why isn't InteractiveLoginEvent not fired with Symfony's 5.1 new security system?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-security, symfony-eventdispatcher

With the new Symfony 5.1 security system, I'm not able to fire the `InteractiveLoginEvent`.

I followed the configuration in the official documentation ([here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html) and [here](https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/session/locale_sticky_session.html)) and the system was working perfectly in the former security system.

Below is my security.yaml :

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            entry_point: form_login
            
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: logout
```

And the UserLocalSuscriber :

```
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;

class UserLocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        if ($user->getLocale() !== null) {
            $this->session->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onInteractiveLogin',
        ];
    }
}
```

How to configure it correctly? Without it, the user locale is not set properly once the user has been logged in.

Comment: The question is remarkably similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264934/symfony-5-security-interactive-login-event-not-called/63269255#63269255

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Symfony's new security system, the `SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` has been replaced with `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\LoginSuccessEvent`.

Change your subscriber to listen for this one:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\LoginSuccessEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class UserLocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            LoginSuccessEvent::class => 'onLoginSuccess',
        ];
    }

    public function onLoginSuccess(LoginSuccessEvent $event): void
    {
        //...
    }

}
```

These new events are mentioned briefly in the [blog with the announcement](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-updated-security-system) for the new authenticator system.

The rest of the documentation has not been updated yet, the new auth system will probably become the default on a future Symfony realese, but right now it still is an **experimental feature**.

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method `onSecurityInteractivelogin()`